# recaptcha doesn't work in Vue component.give grecaptcha.render is not a function when grecaptcha not loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recaptcha

how to add grecaptcha onload method in Vue component.when not loaded grecaptcha.render is not a function

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
 script.src = `${URL}?render=explicit&hl=TR`;
 script.async = true;
 script.defer = true;
 document.body.appendChild(script);
 this.initReCaptcha();


initReCaptcha: function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
       if (typeof grecaptcha === 'undefined') {
           this.initReCaptcha();
       } else {
          grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
          sitekey: 'XXXX',
          callback: this.submit,
          'expired-callback': this.expired
                        });
                    }
                }.bind(this), 100);
            }
```

is working when i set the timeout 1000.but it's too late.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The recaptcha script was updated last **May 4, 2018 9:07:30.349 PM GMT** (based on the timestamp of the recaptcha script). The grecaptcha is being loaded, however the render function has a delay that is why the recaptcha is not being displayed in the UI (**grecaptcha.render is not a functio**n). The possible fix is to validate the *render* function before attempting to load the recaptcha.

Here is the fix:

```
initReCaptcha: function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (typeof grecaptcha === 'undefined' || typeof grecaptcha.render ==='undefined') {
            this.initReCaptcha();
        } else {
            grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
                sitekey: 'XXXX',
                callback: this.submit,
                'expired-callback': this.expired
            });
        }
    }.bind(this), 100);
}
```

I hope it will help you. Cheers

** *Fixed condition as qRoC wrote in comments, thanks.*

Comment: Needs ||, because grecaptcha can be defined, but grecaptcha.render is not

Comment: calling this.initReCaptcha(); grecaptcha.render is not a function console.log error is fixed, but the ReCaptcha is not loaded FYI there is no errors in console.log but ReCaptcha.render ==='undefined' entered into if condition on the first load, if I refresh everything working fine captcha is loading and in console no errors.

Answer (score 3):

I found that out that since two days ago a lot of people got the error:

```
 grecaptcha.render is not a function
```

Well, this works for me. Maybe it helps someone in the

I break it into peaces so you can read it easily:

```
mounted(){
    if (typeof grecaptcha === "undefined") {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit";
        script.onload = this.renderWait;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    } else this.render();
}
```

If grecaptcha is not loaded I will create a script and wait for it to be loaded.
If so renderWait is called

```
renderWait() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (typeof grecaptcha !== "undefined" && typeof grecaptcha.render !== "undefined")  this.render();
            else this.renderWait();
        }, 200);
},
```

When we have finally grecaptcha render it:

```
render() {
        const recaptchaDiv = document.createElement('div');
        recaptchaDiv.className = 'outside-badge';
        document.body.appendChild(recaptchaDiv);

        this.widgetId = grecaptcha.render(recaptchaDiv, {
            sitekey: this.sitekey,
            size: "invisible",
            badge: this.badge || "bottomright",
            theme: this.theme || "light",
            callback: token => {
                this.callback(token);
                grecaptcha.reset(this.widgetId);
            }
        });
        this.loaded = true;
 },
```

Maybe it helps you :)