# How do I load reCAPTCHA Score and Checkbox on the same page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp, recaptcha

Currently on a login page, I need to have both the score and checkbox reCaptcha evaluation on the same page, if the score fails I need to dynamically load the checkbox score.

Currently I have it working although I don't know if I implemented it correctly.

In my HTML header I have

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=${Login.reCaptchaScoreKey}"></script>`

and in the html body I have

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=explicit"></script>`

In AJAX to load the checkbox I have:

```
 var captchaContainer = grecaptcha.render('captcha_container', {
              'sitekey' : siteKey,
              'callback' : function() {
                $("#LOGIN").prop('disabled', false);
              }
});
```

and to submit the score I have the following (I'm attaching the reCaptcha generated token to an HTML element since it was the only way I could figure out to send it to my backend):

```
grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(function() {
                grecaptcha.enterprise.execute(scoreKey, {action: action}).then(function(token) {
                    $('#g-recaptcha-response').val(token);
                    submitForm();
                });
              });
```

It seems strange that I need to include the reCaptcha JS file twice for this to work which is a bit of a code smell.  If I remove the first JS file as expected my score reCaptcha breaks, if I remove the second my checkbox breaks.

Is there a way to do what I want to do by including the reCaptcha JS only once?  Or is the way that I'm doing it okay?

Comment: Refer to: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-run-recaptcha-v2-and-v3-on-the-same-page perhaps?

Comment: Thanks @ssBarBee, I did see that document before posting, the steps to incorporate both V2 and V3 on the same page didn't seem to work for reCaptcha Enterprise score and checkbox,  if I only include the first JS file as indicated in the document, I get: `grecaptcha.render is not a function` when I try to render the checkbox.  Additionally adding `grecaptcha.ready` didn't seem to fix my problem :/

Comment: @Nicolasome Will this Answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158132/recaptcha-doesnt-work-in-vue-component-give-grecaptcha-render-is-not-a-function/50224757#50224757

Comment: @SamJoshua It does not, but I received an answer from the Google support team.  I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an official response for the reCAPTCHA Enterprise support team:

> Thanks for reaching out here. We recommend not putting a checkbox
> behind a score. More details are available on this here:
> https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/faq#id_like_to_use_the_score_from_to_show_a_challenge_checkbox_widget_how_can_i_do_this
>
> Not only are there concerns listed in that FAQ point about the
> efficacy of a checkbox widget when placed behind a score, but it also
> over simplifies how the checkbox widget works. We perform "adversarial
> challenging" on our checkbox widget (essentially, we show harder
> challenges to known attackers), but we're unable to do so when placed
> behind a score reCAPTCHA.
>
> All of this being said, if you do wish to do it anyway, you would
> have to include the JS file twice.

And this is from the link posted in their email:

> I'd like to use the score from reCAPTCHA Enterprise to show a challenge / checkbox widget. How can I do this?
>
> We recommend that you do not do this. reCAPTCHA Enterprise expects to
> see both good and bad user behavior on implementation. If you trigger
> a reCAPTCHA Enterprise checkbox widget based on a reCAPTCHA Enterprise
> score, the checkbox widget is only being exposed to bad traffic. Due
> to this, the widget can have a more difficult time determining whether
> to show a challenge or not. This can result in issuing NO CAPTCHAs (no
> challenge shown at all) to fraudulent users or bots due to trouble
> making that differentiation.
>
> In these cases, we recommend just using a challenge-based site key
> upfront (like reCAPTCHA Enterprise with a CHECKBOX Site Key) instead,
> but installing a SCORE Site Key on every page, as well as issuing
> grecaptcha.enterprise.execute to train the model, but foregoing
> assessments on the SCORE tokens. Essentially, this achieves the goal
> by training the reCAPTCHA Enterprise CHECKBOX site keys on user
> behavior, resulting in less challenges shown to legitimate users and
> more challenges to fraudulent ones.

Comment: Hello @Nicolasome, so what was your solution? Did you switch back to checkbox recaptcha? 

I'd like to do almost the same what you wanted to do: use score-based on login button and show challenge widget if the score was low.

Comment: @MikeYermolayev We ended up separating out our recaptcha migration project into 2 phases.  Phase 1 move from recaptcha free to enterprise checkbox.  Step 2 enterprise checkbox to score/2FA

Comment: It's worth mentioning for phase 1 we also installed the SCORE Site Key on every page as suggested to train the model

Comment: thank you. 
I've ended up switching to hcaptcha.com as they support invisible captcha with challenge and docs look easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Adding to your own answer, check https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#can-i-run-recaptcha-v2-and-v3-on-the-same-page for more detail of you still want to do it.

Comment: I did see that document before posting. Unfortunately, the steps to incorporate both V2 and V3 on the same page didn't seem to work for reCaptcha Enterprise score and checkbox.  The steps you sent says to only include 1 JS file but if I only include only the first JS file as indicated in the document, I get: `grecaptcha.render` is not a function when I try to render the checkbox with enterprise.